# How to place a marker on Google Maps in Chrome?

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome

If I search for a place location on Google Maps, that location shows up with a red marker (for example a University). If I click on any other location on the map (for example a museum) the first red mark goes away and a new red mark appears at the new location.

How do I add markers on any custom locations on the map?

I don't need to be able to find directions or get distances, I just want to put up markers so that I can get an estimate of how close or far the various places are.

Is there any way to do this while viewing Google Maps in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be signed into a Google account to do this.

When you are, you can use the Save button in the legend to save the place as a favourite,

[image]

All your favourite places show with a star when you look at a view that includes the place.

[image]

If you have so many favourites that a view is confusing, then you may want to delete some:   from the hamburger menu (three lines in the right of the search box), click  **Your places > Saved**  and you can see and manage your list of favourites.

if the location you want to save is not already a Place in maps, then you need to add a private label for this to work.   Read about that [here](https://www.google.com/gmm/answer/6257830).